# Launch React Native App from Background on Notification Received

Tags: react-native

I am working on react native application and my requirement is to launch specific screen on Notification received.

Notification is working fine in all state i.e. Foreground or background.

I am using below library:

```
react-navigation
@react-native-firebase/messaging
react-native-push-notification
```

Below is the code for handling notification :

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
  let text = {
    title: remoteMessage.data.title,
    body: remoteMessage.data.body,
  }
  notif.cancelAll();
  notif.localNotif(text);
  NavigationService.navigate('Contact', { userName: 'Lucy' })
});
```

Also wrote a navigation code on notification received method referring

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop

I can see app navigate to particular screen but its not launching app.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: hi, did you solve this? thank you